# VBA OnError Exception Handling not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have following sample code in my VBA. Whenever i face system related error, i want to display the my own error message. But the following code is not working.

VBA tells

> Type Mismatch

I want

> Hello your date is invalid

My Code

```
Sub good()

Dim date_ As Date
date_ = "hello"

On Error GoTo Err1:

Err1:
    MsgBox "Hello your date is invalid"
    ' more code

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `On Error` statement *before* an error occurs, usually at the very beginning of the procedure. Think of the `On Error` statement as a directive that tells VBA how to handle any errors that are encountered later in the procedure.

```
Sub good()

On Error GoTo Err1

Dim date_ As Date
date_ = "hello"

Exit Sub 'Make sure you include this so successful executions 
         'don't continue into the error block.

Err1:
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case 101 'Not the actual error number!
         MsgBox "Hello your date is invalid"
      Case 102 'Not the actual error number!
         MsgBox "Something else bad happened!"
      Case Else
         MsgBox "I don't know what happened - unexpected error!"
    End Select
    ' more code

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.. Works fine..
But what if i dont know where the error occurs ?

Comment: You don't need to know where the error occurs. Put all error handling at the end of the procedure in a separate error handling block.

Comment: @Logan: That's why you place the error statement before any place you expect an error to happen, i.e. in your case at the very top...

Comment: @Logan Please consider accepting this answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: @PeterAlbert : If i have 2 different datatype and if i want to raise exception, do i need to write OnError seperately on top of each datatypes ?

Comment: @logan No, you can just test `Err.Number` in your error handling block. Each error will likely have a different error number, so you can use `Select Case Err.Number` in your error handling block to handle each error appropriately.

Comment: @logan I've added an example of how to handle this in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the `On Error` statement before the error!

Also, don't forget the `Exit Sub`at the end, else your routine will always run the error code:

```
Sub good()
    Dim date_ As Date

    On Error GoTo Err1:
    date_ = "hello"

    On Error Goto 0 'goes back to default, i.e. show debugger
    Exit Sub

Err1:
    MsgBox "Hello your date is invalid"
    ' more code

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can do this

```
Sub good()
    Dim date_ As Date

    On Error Resume Next
    date_ = "hello"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Wrong type"
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Goto 0

    ' more code

End Sub
```

This approach can be repeated to catch individual errors...

Comment: If i have 2 different datatypes and if i want to raise different exception, do i need to write OnError seperately on top of each datatypes ?